# Selenium - How to handle popup with event listener (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, event-handling, listener

I'm using selenium with C# (default browser - FireFoX).

There are some sites that popup message after unknown time (if any).

I can't use wait or sleep, because I don't know on which screen the popup will appear. Using  'try-Catch' on each page is not very smart....

The solution I thought of, is to use an event listener to listen to the popup/s and then it will clicks the 'X' button. Of course the listener has to be in a Thread, and each test might have an array of Threads that gets the list of events and xpath/ ID's.

Did anyone do such things? Is there any example / article / tutorial to help me with it ?

10X,

Gil

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of an old Chinese [proverb](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/2279.html), when faced with such questions, I go to the SeleniumHQ github repository and look at the [tests](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/test/webdriverbackedselenium/TestAlerts.cs).

You want your wait time to be small so that you don't waste too much time waiting when no alert is present. You can call the pop-up handling code when a page opens or just before your test leaves that page; depends on your application's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply override the FirefoxDriver to automatically accept the alert and silence the alert exception:

```
class FirefoxDriverEx : FirefoxDriver {

    private static DesiredCapabilities Capabilities() {
        var capa = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        capa.SetCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "accept");
        return capa;
    }

    public FirefoxDriverEx()
        : base(Capabilities()) { }

    protected override Response Execute(string driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary<string, object> parameters) {
        try{
            return base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException) {
            return base.Execute(driverCommandToExecute, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a usage example:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriverEx();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts");
driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[.='Click for JS Alert']").Click();
string text = driver.FindElementById("result").Text;
```

Comment: Cool.  I only see *UnexpectedAlertBehavior* in the c# and Javascript selenium libraries.